# Вывести сообщение из Edit в excel?

Tags: c++, mfc

В лабе необходимо создать проект MFC. Кинуть один edit и кнопку. Через odbc подключить excel как бд. Вывод edit в excel в итоге.

Подключить и создать получилось, а вот как вывести в excel - не знаю. Методичка написана для C++ v 6.0 
Там предлагается использовать функцию m_pSet. Но в Visual studio 2017 найти ее не могу.

Comment: *Подключить и создать получилось* - и не покажете, что сделано своими руками?

Comment: По логике через odbc, если так просят, открываем конструктор и вперёд... :)

Comment: Форма с подключенной через ODBC excel'кой.